Estimation of variance for MoM estimates
In a paper from mid-1900s, an author estimated parameters of a distribution by solving $\hat{h}=M^{-1}c$ driven by the MoM. Here, $c$ and $M$ are a vector and a matrix in terms of moments ($m_r'$), and $h$ is a vector of estimators, say $\theta_1,\cdots,\theta_n$. Then, the author estimated the asymptotic variance of $h$ by using a special type of the Delta method that appears in the Kendall's Advanced Theory of Statistics Vol 1 section 9.6. This method uses $\text{var}(f(x))\approx\text{E}\left[\left(\sum_{i}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(m_i)\Delta x_i\right)^2\right]$, where $m_r$ is a $r$th central moment. Briefly, in the paper, the author states$$dh=M^{-1}(dc-dM\cdot h),$$ where derivates were taken respect to $m_r'$. Then, $$V(\hat{h})=\Sigma^{-1}\text{E}[(dc-dM\cdot h)(dc-dM\cdot h)^T]\Sigma^{-T},$$
where $\Sigma$ is the matrix of the population parameters corresponding to $M$ (which I am not sure what this really means, but I think it should be $M$).
I have two questions regarding this paper.

I would like to know if this paper utilizes the method correctly. Is the approximation really true for moments ($m_r'$)?
Do you have any clue what $\Sigma$ is?


Please cite the paper.
